# Why do so many spam emails lately contain a lot of unicode characters?

Tags: spam, unicode

I receive a lot of spam email (probably from recent breaches). A lot of them contain text that looks a lot like the below text:

[image]

Why do they contain such weird characters? Is this part of an exploit? Is this to mislead spam filters? Or is it for a different reason?

Comment: That's probably an encoding error, using the wrong character set to display e.g. [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). If you paste the actual text rather than using an image, I could try transcoding it to Unicode equivalents. If you paste the actual raw .eml content (with headers) in a code block, we might be better equipped to speculate on the email.

Comment: @AdamKatz Once I get home I'll see what I can do. I use Outlook so I'll have to first figure out how to export these mails as EML

Comment: I see localized spam from some regions where they basically assume that everyone is using the same character set and so it doesn't have to be explicitly stated, in violation of pertinent email RFCs. Maybe a client which is popular in the region displays it like they expected, and they don't care, or simply didn't notice that it's broken for other recipients.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually those are UTF8 sequences that resemble other characters, without being them.

For example   is not the text "this string", and therefore does not trigger UCE detectors as spam, while *you* probably read it as "this string", as the sender intended.

On the other hand, it *is* weirdly encoded, so it can happen that it is decoded incorrectly. And " " becomes ����������� or other [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

Comment: If you are curious: These are "Maths Alphanumeric Symbols" starting at U1D400. Four byte UTF-8.   is nearby.